# Automatic addslashes while returing my own template tag in Django

Tags: python, django, django-templates, template-engine

I'm a noob django programmer and I want to create my own template tag for the Django templates. I've created a templatetags module and it seems to work properly when I use the shown code; However, my function returns a string with `"&lt;"` and `"&gt;"` instead of `"<"` and `">"` (As if the result of the function would had been modified by `addslashes()` function). What's wrong with my code?

**base_template.html (django template that uses my template tag)**

```
<% load templatetags %>
<html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
   {# text contains a string #}
   {{ text | formattedtext }}
 </body>
</html>
```

**templatetags.py**

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()
@register.filter(name='formattedtext')

def formattedtext(value):
    try:
        scoringTemplate = "<b>" + value + "</b>"
        print scoringTemplate #return string with "<b>text</b>"
        return scoringTemplate #however, this returns string with "&lt;text&gt;" value :(
    except ValueError:
        return value
    except:
        return value
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to mark the output as 'safe':
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.safestring.mark_safe

So, your code should become:

```
from django import template
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

register = template.Library()
@register.filter(name='formattedtext')

def formattedtext(value):
    try:
        scoringTemplate = "<b>" + value + "</b>"
        print scoringTemplate #return string with "<b>text</b>"
        return mark_safe(scoringTemplate)   # unescaped, raw html
    except ValueError:
        return value
    except:
        return value
```